# python executable app not running on other systems

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, tkinter.iconbitmap

I compiled my code into an executable app on my system using pyinstaller. the app is running well on my system. but when I transfer the app to another system and try to run it, it throws up an error.

This is the error below

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "app15.py", line 44, in <module>
 File "customtkinter\windows\ctk_tk.py", line 232, in iconbitmap'
```

I know this issue has to do with the bitmap icon

Note that the app runs well on my system and the icon is correctly displayed when I run the exec file on my system but gives an error when i try to run it on another system. I compiled it with the code `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole app1.py`.

Comment: In these questions does any of solutions help you: [compatibility between Pyinstaller and Tkinter icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23554142/21350362), [load a path independent image ... making the executable independent from the image path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52646089/21350362)?

Answer (score 0):

The icon most likely has to be in the same directory as the app itself.
you can package the exe with the icon using --add-data